# How to pad all audio in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, headphones

I am using Windows 10. When using headphones I have to keep the volume at 2-3% to prevent my ears from being blown out. I would like more control than this, however. Is it possible to pad all sounds by a given percentage?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, you could try turning on loudness equalization for your headphones in the audio device settings panel. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to get to it if you need it:

1. Right click the speaker icon on the taskbar and click **Playback Devices**
   (if this isn't visible on the taskbar, click the **^** on the right side of the taskbar to show hidden icons. It should be there)
2. On the playback devices panel, right click the device entry for your headphones and click **Properties**
3. On the properties panel, click **Enhancements** to switch to the enhancements tab
4. Check the box labeled **Loudness Equalization**
5. Click **Apply** and **OK** to close both dialogue boxes

Loudness equalization should now be enabled for the device, and hopefully your ears won't be blown out anymore.

I know this question is over a year old and probably not relevant to you anymore, but I figured I might as well post this in hopes it helps someone in a similar situation.